# Почему знак доллара без объявления выводит тип "функция"?

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. Я только начал изучать JavaScript и столкнулся с такой вещью.

В учебнике Ильи Кантора есть такой момент[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть вопроса. Если не объявлять никаких переменных и прописать код 
`alert(typeof $);`, то функция алерт покажет в окне тип "функция". Где об этом можно почитать или это ошибка дизайна языка? Ведь он должен был выдать `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Chrome консоль предоставляет [Command line api](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference)

Одна из функций предоставляемых консолью: [`$(selector)`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselector), является синонимом для функции [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

---

Исходя из вышесказанного, результат выполнения `typeof $` будет зависеть от конкретного браузера и api, которые он предоставляет, например для `EDGE` результат будет ожидаемый *undefined*, а вот в FF, будет та же функция.

---

Определить встроенная это функция или библиотечная можно простым вызовом `toString`: в случае библиотечной функции выведется ее код, в случае встроенной - будет строка содержащая `[Command Line API]` либо `[native code]`