# Чем отличаются два обращения к элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В чем отличие в JS между `document.getElementById("element")` и 
`$('#element')`?
И первое и второе выбирают элемент по id

Comment: Возвращают  разные вещи, во втором случчае будет JQuery Object. И работать с двумя результатами нужно так же по разному

Comment: Возможно связанный вопрос: [Почему знак доллара без объявления выводит тип “функция”?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/792198/186999)

Answer (score 5):

1. Условия использования: второй вариант требует подключения библиотеки
2. Передаваемые параметры: в обе функции передаётся строка, однако в [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) передаётся сам ID, а в [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) (она же `$()`) - #ID (так как она работает не только с ID элементов)
3. Возвращаемое значение: `getElementById()` возвращает [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element) или `null`, `jQuery()` - [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) объект
4. Производительность: функция `jQuery()`работает не только с ID элементов, поэтому ей нужно время на анализ переданных параметров. И в итоге она всё равно вызовет внутри себя `getElementById()`. Так что первый вариант работает быстрее

Answer (score 4):

Ничем не отличаются. Первый написан на JS, а второй тоже на JS только с использованием библиотеки jQuery (поэтому в этом случая требуется ее подключить).

Comment: Не совсем верно, ведь jQuery объект имеет специфические свойства и методы

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен